# What is the effect of weapon weight?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does weight affect the cooldown of my abilties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53844/how-does-weight-affect-the-cooldown-of-my-abilties)

Does weapon weight affect anything other than recharge time?

How does it affect recharge time (cool down periods get longer, but by how much and what are the weight limits?)

Comment: This is a dupe. Lemme find it.

Comment: I suppose also related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53559/10260